# Contract expired, boss suggests a new offer after I left and started a new job search

Tags: human-resources, contracts, termination

I had recently asked a question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110419/my-contract-is-expiring-and-it-wont-be-renewed-yet-im-in-the-midst-of-a-crucia) sometime back regarding my ending contract situation given that it was in the course of a crucial project involving my employers, and I got some pretty decent suggestions on how to go about it. So April came to an end I've cleared all my employee status with the organisation (Including handing over to the new incoming IT Staff person) I was working for and I'm on the hunt for a new job. My boss has then informed me out of the blue that they would consider taking me again to continue with what I was doing, something that should have been done earlier if they actually wanted to retain me, rather than wait till I was gone and even handed over everything.

I am thinking that in the event I decide to go back and finish this pending project, I would do it on a consultant/client basis and not as a fulltime employee as it was intially. My questions are:

1. Should I accept any offer to rejoin the company to continue working after having exited?

Comment: We can't tell you what you should do as only you know what you want to do.  But on the other hand you seem to be in the position to negotiate better terms.

Comment: I'm a little confused, you were a full-time employee, but had a contract with a fixed end date?  That seems more like a contractor role in the original scenario

Comment: There was no fixed end date, the contract was terminated in the course of it's running.

Answer (score 6):

You should not accept *any* offer. You should accept an offer that is based on your value to the company, with compensation for having lost your job and income for some time.

And your value to the company is very, very high right now. The minimum would be say a 50% raise with the money guaranteed for six months. You can probably get more. Meanwhile look for other opportunities.